# Json, average of marks in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

i Have json like that but bigger, and i need average of any DB,TV,... there is not only 1 student but more here is only exam how to in javascript

```
[
  {
    "Petr Prochazka": {
        "DB": [
            "5",
            "4",
            "2",
            "4",
            "4",
            "2"
        ],
        "TV": [
            "4",
            "1",
            "2",
            "2",
            "4",
            "5",
            "5",
            "5"
        ],
```

Comment: I don't really understand what it is you want to do. If that is an example of the structure before processing it, could you add an example of how it would look afterwards? Oh, evolutions edit made it make sense to me :)

Comment: What kind of average? 'mean', 'median', 'mode', etc?

Comment: An average for each student or the average of ALL students?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: The problem I'm having with this question is the data structure. As of now its an array of objects, however what doesnt come across is whether or not the first element has many students or one student per element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.